# Change WordPress get_bloginfo('url'); or permalink domain for posts published before a certain date

Tags: wordpress

A WordPress site has recently changed from .co.uk to .org. As soon as this was done, it affected Facebook Comments data as the URL it was mapped to had changed. This is the code within single.php to call the comments:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-num-posts="3" data-width="620"></div>
```

Now that the_permalink() has changed, I want to output the following as a function:

```
if post is published before 29th Jan 2012 output this:
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.domain.co.uk/post-permalink/" data-num-posts="3" data-width="620"></div>
otherwise output this:
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.domain.org/post-permalink/" data-num-posts="3" data-width="620"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know if I am missing something, but shouldn't it be as easy as writing a small (cli-)script fetching all wp_posts WHERE permalink LIKE domain.co.uk, replace co.uk with .org it and then UPDATE wp_posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok to start with
Step 1: Open the theme folder you are using.
Step 2: Open the function.php in any editor and copy the following function there.

```
 if(! function_exists('facebook_comments')):
function facebook_comments(){
    $org_post_date = strtotime(get_the_date());
    $earlier_date = strtotime("29 January 2012");
    if($org_post_date <= $earlier_date)
    {
        echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.domain.co.uk/post-permalink/" data-num-posts="3" data-width="620"></div>
';

    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.domain.org/post-permalink/" data-num-posts="3" data-width="620"></div>';

    }
}
endif;
```

Step 3: Now save it and open your loop-single.php or single.php where you have placed your facebook comment div and replace that with the following code.

Step 4: Save it and Run.

This will definitely work.

Enjoy.

Thanks
Rahul.

Comment: Aah !! the code line after step 3 is missing it will be `<?php facebook_comments(); ?>`

Comment: ok. so now, what is the variable in code that replicates a different peramlink domain. for example http://domain.co.uk/%permalink%/ and http://domain.org/%permalink%/ (the second can now simply be the_permalink())

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do something like

```
if(the_time('F j, Y') => date([date format here which matches the_time() function], mktime(0,0,0, 1, 29, 2012)))
{
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.domain.org/post-permalink/" data-num-posts="3" data-width="620"></div>
}
else
{
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.domain.co.uk/post-permalink/" data-num-posts="3" data-width="620"></div>
}
```

Comment: ok - so from this how can i use the permalink structure based on the new domain? i.e. domain.co.uk/%postname%/ and the_permalink?